# Locating the user position via state toggle - React.js & custom hook

Tags: react.js

I display the current user location, using `Geolocation` - and activate/cancel it according to button click and map view.
This is managed by the state `isLocateUser`.

- When the app is ready, the default state `isLocateUser` is `T`, the `Map` component renders and looking for the current user location, via the custom hook `useWatchLocation`.
- However, when the user drags the map, the state `isLocateUser` set to `F` and locating is cancelled.
- The user can re-activate it, by clicking the button in the component `LocateUser`, that set the state `isLocateUser` back to `T`.

This works fine.

However, I am not sure that the custom hook and this toggling between the states is efficient enough.

**Are there any better ways to rewrite this hook, in order to be more suitable to that scenario?**

You can see the code below:

- Map (Based on OpenStreetMaps & Leaflet)

  ```
   export const Map = (props) => {
     const currLocationOptions = useWatchLocation(
       props.isLocateUser,
       geolocationOptions
     );

     useEffect(() => {
       if (!currLocationOptions.location) return;
     }, [currLocationOptions.location, currLocationOptions.cancelLocationWatch]);

     function handleCancelLocationWatch() {
       currLocationOptions.cancelLocationWatch();
       props.setIsLocateUser(false);
     }

   // . . . . . .

     return (
       <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom}>
         <CurrUserPosition
           isLocateUser={props.isLocateUser}
           location={currLocationOptions.location}
           error={currLocationOptions.error}
         ></CurrUserPosition>
         <HandleMapEvents
           isLocateUser={props.isLocateUser}
           setIsLocateUser={props.setIsLocateUser}
           handleCancelLocationWatch={handleCancelLocationWatch}
         ></HandleMapEvents>

         // . . . . . .

       </MapContainer>
     );
   };
  ```
- useWatchLocation

  ```
       const useWatchLocation = (isLocateUser, options = {}) => {
         // store location in state
         const [location, setLocation] = useState();

         // store error message in state
         const [error, setError] = useState();

         // save the returned id from the geolocation's `watchPosition` to be able to cancel the watch instance
         const locationWatchId = useRef(null);

         // Success handler for geolocation's `watchPosition` method
         const handleSuccess = (pos) => {
           const { latitude, longitude } = pos.coords;

           setLocation({latitude, longitude});
         };

         // Error handler for geolocation's `watchPosition` method
         const handleError = (error) => {
           // . . . . .
           setError(errorMsg);
         };

         // Clears the watch instance based on the saved watch id
         const cancelLocationWatch = () => {
           if (locationWatchId.current && navigator.geolocation) {
             navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(locationWatchId.current);
           }
         };

         useEffect(() => {
           if (!isLocateUser) return;

           // If the geolocation is not defined in the used browser we handle it as an error
           if (!navigator.geolocation) {
             setError(getString("GEOLOCATION_NOT_SUPPORTED"));
             return;
           }

           // Start to watch the location with the Geolocation API
           locationWatchId.current = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
             handleSuccess,
             handleError,
             options
           );


           // Clear the location watch instance when React unmounts the used component
           return cancelLocationWatch;
         }, [isLocateUser, options]);

         return { location, cancelLocationWatch, error };
       };

       export default useWatchLocation;
  ```
- HandleMapEvents

  ```
   function HandleMapEvents(props) {
     const map = useMapEvents({    
       moveend: () => {
         if (props.isLocateUser != null && props.isLocateUser) {
           props.setIsLocateUser(false);
           props.handleCancelLocationWatch();
         }
       },
       // . . . . .
     });
     return null;
   }
  ```
- LocateUser

  ```
       export const LocateUser = (props) => {
         return (
           <button
             className="locate"
             onClick={() => {
               props.setIsLocateUser(true);
               getAlert("startLocationWatch");
             }}
           >
           </button>
         );
       };
  ```